# Как правильно передать значения в запросе sql в БД Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

У менять есть БД с разными типами (INT, VARCHAR, DATA)
Как мне правильно сделать запрос sql, передавая стандартные (пустые) значения, не зная настроек полей в БД?
Я делаю так

```
INSERT users (id,m_domain,t_domain,status,shop,email,nick,comment,date,price,order_id) VALUES (DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT,DEFAULT)
```

Проблема в том, что если у поля в БД нету стандартного значения, получаю ошибку. Раньше передавал NULL везде, но это работает так же если у всех полей в БД есть галочка "Null". Можно ли как то сделать проверку в sql, или есть какой то стандартный параметр для переменных.

Comment: Код всегда предполагает, что структура известна. Поэтому ситуации, когда тип данных поля или наличие значения по умолчанию неизвестны, быть не доджно в принципе.

Answer (score 0):

Нет каких-то общих стандартных пустых значений для разных типов данных. Если вы сами не определяете какое-то значение по умолчанию для столбца, то MySQL не предложит что-то своё. Просто будет столбец без значения по умолчанию. Вставляя строки в таблицу, вы должны указать значения столбцов. По-хорошему, надо указать значения всех столбцов.

Надо заметить, что базы данных могут быть использованы двумя способами. Первый -- это использование базы данных как хранилища данных программы. Все операции с базой делает программа, и значения по умолчанию определяет и контролирует программа. Второй случай -- это использование базы данных как самостоятельного инструмента. Операции с базой делаются руками пользователя через SQL-интерфейс.

Так вот, в программе очень просто перечислить все столбцы и значения (в том числе значения по умолчанию). Вы пишете код один раз и потом он работает снова и снова без участия человека.

```php
<?php

// ...

$db->query('
    insert into `users`
    set
        `m_domain` = :m_domain,
        `t_domain` = :t_domain,
        `status` = :status,
        `shop` = :shop,
        `email` = :email,
        `nick` = :nick,
        `comment` = :comment,
        `date` = :date,
        `price` = :price,
        `order_id` = :order_id
', [
    ':m_domain' => '',
    ':t_domain' => '',
    ':status' => 'active',
    ':shop' => null,
    ':email' => '',
    ':nick' => '',
    ':comment' => 'default comment',
    ':date' => date('Y-m-d'),
    ':price' => 0,
    'order_id' => null,
]);
```

Если же предполагается, что базой будут пользоваться вручную. То тогда используют такие фишки как default. При создании таблицы, всем столбцам, вводить которые не обязательно, указываются значения по умолчанию. И их можно просто пропустить в запросе.

```sql
insert into `users` set `email` = 'email@example.com'
```

Таким образом, определить значения по умолчанию это ваша задача. И эти значения не всегда зависят от типа данных в MySQL. Для температуры тела человека значение по умолчанию может быть **36.6** градусов цельсия, а для геометрического угла **0.0** радиан. Но не увлекайтесь, помните, что база данных нужна для хранения реальных данных, а не значений по умолчанию :-)

P.S.

В базе хранятся и данные о схемах ваших таблиц, о столбцах и их типах. Если вам любопытно можно ли в принципе написать универсальный запрос, который вставит строчку в любую таблицу MySQL, то гляньте в сторону [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html).

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ